# How do I add Space under List in HTML

Tags: html, list

Maby this question is too basic for me to find an answer, but I got to ask it anyway.
I am using a list in HTML like this:

```html
<ol>
  <li>I want some [...] Space between</li>
  <li>Something second</li> 
</ol>
```

(EDIT: Please imagine, that the line-break is kind of random, because for example the line is too long. I cannot add a span on specific places in my case)

And the result is something like this:

```
1. I want some [...]
Space between
2. Something second
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
1. I want some [...]
   Space between
2. Something second
```

How do I do that?

Comment: I don't see any difference from the [result](https://jsfiddle.net/vnyhf83d/) and what you want it to look like.

Comment: The output I'm getting and what you want are the same.

Answer (score 0):

To get a bigger gap between the list elements you need to add the following CSS. The bigger the padding-bottom value, the bigger the gap between the list elements.

```
li {
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first want to wrap the first list item with a span tag, and add the CSS property, tab-size.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li>I want some <br><span class="tab">Space between</span></li>
        <li>Something second</li> 
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
.tab {
    tab-size: 1;
}
```

Comment: What can I do when the Line is too long? Something like

<ol>
        <li>This line is sooooooooo long that it gets into next line but I dont want to 
         control where</li>
        <li>Something second</li> 
    </ol>

Comment: If you are on the normal zoom scale, 100%, the first list item shouldn't go to the second when you didn't declare a break. When you zoom in, the long list item would shrink to the line below, but still maintaining the gap between the counting numbers and the text.

Comment: My sentenceces in the real case are way loger than the example. So there is a line break

Answer (score 0):

You can add the text to an element and style it.
Below I added a span and gave it a -ve left margin.

```css
span{
    color:red;
    margin-left:-1em;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>I want some <br> <span>Space between</span></li>
<li>Something second</li> 
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

You make the text you want to have space between a `<span>` element, set its display style to `block`, and add a line break Unicode character (`\A`) before it:

```css
li span {
  display: block;
}

li span::before {
  content: "\A";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>I want some [...] <span> Space between</span></li>
  <li>Something second</li>
</ol>
```